# How to deal with personalization files in git repo

Tags: git, python-sphinx

I am working on a Sphinx project in a Git repository and there is a personalization (`conf.py`) file which is included in the repository, but should be kept unique for each user (or at least for me). Is there a way to configure Git to keep the local copy of this file untracked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good explanation how to proceed in this case - 
[Keep local modifications in Git-tracked files](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/20/keep-local-modifications-in-git-tracked-files/)

> the magic words are:
>
> `git update-index --skip-worktree FILENAME`
>
> Where “FILENAME” is the name of the file I want to keep local changes
>   in.
>
> There’s a matching “–no-skip-worktree” to flip that bit back off.
>
> With this bit set on a file, local changes to the file will not show
>   up in git status listings.

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to the [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file, and commit **the .gitignore file**.

This way, any local changes you make to `conf.py` will be ignored by git, and you could have each user keep his or her own configuration locally.